# UserManager throws exception - Unable to track an entity because primary key property 'Id' is null - after upgrading from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I've used the custom implementation of `User` which is derivated from `IdentityUser` using `Asp.Net Core Identity`:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        ...
    }
```

If I call the method:

```
var identityResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
```

I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'AppUser' because primary key property 'Id' is null.

It works perfectly with version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` - `2.2.0`, but after upgrading to `3.0.0` - it doesn't work.

I get same error during testing of the creation of user as well, there I use following `UserManager` configuration:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c95ee2b051814b787b07f55ff224d03d550aafeb/src/Identity/test/Shared/MockHelpers.cs#L37

Comment: Check if `user.Id == null`. There is a [breaking change in EF Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#string-and-byte-array-keys-are-not-client-generated-by-default) related to string keys, but `IdentityUser` class in 3.0 sets the Id to `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` inside the constructor. So you either are using old identity classes, are setting explicitly `Id` to `null,` or are not inheriting `IdentityUser`, but `IdentityUser<string>`.

Comment: User.Id is null, but it works with .net core 2.2. What do you suggest for fixing it?

Comment: Well, make sure it's not null. Or use the suggestion from the breaking change link - under ***Mitigations** The pre-3.0 behavior can be obtained by …*

Comment: You are right, can you please put your tip like answer? I will accept it. I solved this issue via correct mapping. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is EF Core 3.0 introduced breaking change [String and byte array keys are not client-generated by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#string-and-byte-array-keys-are-not-client-generated-by-default) which affects entities which use `string` PK like `IdentityUser<string>` and `IdentityRole<string>` and will cause that exception if the PK is not set explicitly.

However the default `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` classes were also modified to populate the `Id` property with `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` inside class constructors. So normally you shouldn't have that issue except if some code is setting explicitly the `Id` to `null`. Anyway, you can switch to old behavior by using the suggestion from the link

> **Mitigations**
>
> The pre-3.0 behavior can be obtained by explicitly specifying that the key properties should use generated values if no other non-null value is set.

e.g. inside context `OnModelCreating` override, after calling base implementation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
    .Property(e => e.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```