# Unable to track an entity of type because primary key property 'id' is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

After I upgraded to Asp.Net Core 3.0 I am getting the following error for my Identity class when attempting to create a user:

> Unable to track an entity 'User' of type because primary key property
>   'id' is null.

Here User represents my extension of the Identity model.

This is the line of code where the error occurs:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UserManager throws exception - Unable to track an entity because primary key property 'Id' is null - after upgrading from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729749/usermanager-throws-exception-unable-to-track-an-entity-because-primary-key-pro)

Comment: I prefer the formatting of your question, but the linked question is most definitely a duplicate. This question is definitely going to come back as more people migrate so maybe a gold badge holder can decide which becomes the surviving question?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! When I stumbled across this error I wasn’t able to find the thread you mentioned. @AFriend

Comment: Agreed! I can see a lot of People facing this issue as they migrate to Core 3.0 @AFriend

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is due to breaking changes in EF Core 3.0 which can be found under this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#string-and-byte-array-keys-are-not-client-generated-by-default

The problem can be solved by assigning a key manually like this:

```
// assign GUID to Id
user.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

Another solution would be the following according to Microsoft:

> The pre-3.0 behavior can be obtained by explicitly specifying that the
>   key properties should use generated values if no other non-null value
>   is set. For example, with the fluent API:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Blog>()
    .Property(e => e.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Or with data annotations:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 14):

This solved the issue for me.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        var keysProperties = builder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Select(x => x.FindPrimaryKey()).SelectMany(x => x.Properties);
        foreach (var property in keysProperties)
        {
            property.ValueGenerated = ValueGenerated.OnAdd;
        }
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU! perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another reason that can cause this error.

Remove such code (if exists).

```
entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
```

This code is written automatically if you scaffold your existing database (and the column Id was IsIdentity = false) to domain classes.