# How to bind data from different SQL tables using dropdown?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropdown

I am trying to create an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web app using identity. The app has users and admin. The admin can create new tasks and assign them to the users.

I get the list of users and tasks in 2 different dropdowns as follows:
View: Assign.cshtml

```
@model TaskManager2.ViewModels.AssignViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Assign";
}

<h1>Assign</h1>

<h4>Assign</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Assign">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(t => t.TaskId,
            Model.Tasks, "--Select task--")
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.Id,
            Model.Users, "--Select user--")
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

AdminController:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public AdminController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult Assign()
    {
        var users = (from u in _context.Users select new SelectListItem { Value = u.Id, Text = u.FirstName }).ToList();
        var tasks = (from t in _context.Task select new SelectListItem { Value = t.TaskId.ToString(), Text = t.Description }).ToList();

        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault();
        return View(new AssignViewModel { Users = users, Tasks = tasks });
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Assign([Bind("TaskId, Id")] Assign assign)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(assign);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(assign);
    }
```

ViewModel :

```
public class AssignViewModel
{
    public IList<SelectListItem> Tasks;
    public IList<SelectListItem> Users;
    //public long SelectedUserId { get; set; }
    //public long SelectedTaskId { get; set; }
    //Added these lines instead
    public Task TaskId { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser Id { get; set; }
}
```

Model: Assign.cs

```
public partial class Assign
{
    public long AssignId { get; set; }
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I got an error that is asked previously on stackoverflow: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59134406/unable-to-track-an-entity-of-type-because-primary-key-property-id-is-null) and I tried the solution. I added the commented line on Assign.cs but the result that I get is not the one that I want. The idea is to save the Id of the user from AspNetUser and taskId from Task table in a third table called Assign. Here's how it looks like:

[image: assign]
I am new to this, so I don't really understand how it works. I would really appreciate your help! Thank you!
**Edit**
I made the changes to the code above and also set Identity Specification to Yes for the primary key. It works and records the user Id and the corresponding taskId to the database. Now I'm trying to create something like:

```
@if ((bool)ViewData["HasError"]) //not working
{   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">

        Please select!
    </div>
}
```

This will give an alert if the user doesn't select any of the options instead of throwing this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'TaskManager2.Models.Assign', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'TaskManager2.ViewModels.AssignViewModel'.

Comment: Can you explain exactly where the problem is? Are you having problems with your records?

Comment: @MuhammetCaylak thanks a lot for your help! I actually fixed the problem I described above but I have another issue with the same code. When I don't select any options and click create it gives me this error: InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'TaskManager2.Models.Assign', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'TaskManager2.ViewModels.AssignViewModel'. I am trying to create sth that would give a warning instead of the error.

Comment: update your problem?

Comment: @MuhammetCaylak just edited my question

Answer (score 0):

In the http post line, you are sending Assign (entity model)

To the controller, so the model state would be done on Assign class,

I think you should be using AssignViewModel there, because all the interaction with views should happen with viewmodel, if your view model is valid then covert to actual entity.