# Entity Framework Core, unable to set HasName on PrimaryKey

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to access a CosmosDB collection using Entity Framework Core.

My DB has various data, but the primary key is 'id'
My Model has a subset of this, but uses 'Id' instead of 'id'.

I have checked that I am able to read/write to a test DB where it includes a copy of 'id' as 'Id'. This causes no issues.

As far as i can read in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes it should be possible to set the 'HasName' property.

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class TestModel
{
    [DataMember] 
    [JsonProperty("id")] 
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    public string Pid { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>().ToContainer("TestModel");
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>().HasPartitionKey(x => x.Pid);
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>().HasNoDiscriminator();

    modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>().HasKey(b => b.Id).HasName("id");
}
```

Using this, i still get an error.

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'TestModel' because primary key property 'Id' is null.

I have also in trial and error, attempted to use.
 - HasName + HasKey / HasIndex
 - HasColumnName + Property

Comment: Did you get this resolved or are you still looking for a solution? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: I am unable to resolve this @MikeUbezziMSFT any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I am no longer with Microsoft. I hope you are able to or have found a resolution for this. Again, apologize for the delay in responding with an update.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by **breaking changes** in EF Core 3.0, these can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#string-and-byte-array-keys-are-not-client-generated-by-default).

You can probably solve it with the data annotation `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

```
public class TestModel
{
    [DataMember] 
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
(...)
```

and if that doesn't work, a second solution would be to assign a GUID to the id. See this discussion for more info on that https://stackoverflow.com/a/59134407/14344821.

Answer (score 0):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>(entity=> entity.Property(x=>x.ID).HasColumnName("id"))
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers.